# Select column using the value in other row of a data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I need to create a new variable containing the value in one column in a `data.frame` depending on the value of another column, the example goes as follows:

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(pi)
DT <- data.table(
  X1 = LETTERS[1:10],
  X2 = letters[1:10],
  Z = sample(c("X1", "X2"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)

DT[]
```

This code generates the following

```
    X1 X2  Z
 1:  A  a X1
 2:  B  b X2
 3:  C  c X1
 4:  D  d X1
 5:  E  e X2
 6:  F  f X2
 7:  G  g X1
 8:  H  h X1
 9:  I  i X2
10:  J  j X2
```

Now I want to have a column `W` where if column `Z` is "X1" (or "X2") the content on the column `X1` (or `X2`) is selected.

One solution can be:

```
DT[Z == "X1", W := X1]
DT[Z == "X2", W := X2]
```

But I would like to find a more elegant way to do this because I have many  columns where I need to select one entry.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `get` after looping through sequence of rows

```
DT[, W :=  get(Z) , 1:nrow(DT)]
```

Or with `eval(as.name`

```
DT[,  W := eval(as.name(Z)) , 1:nrow(DT)]
```

Comment: Thank you, now the answer look easy but I was stuck in expressions like:   `DT[, W := diag(as.matrix(DT[,DT[, Z], with  = FALSE]))]`

Comment: @EnriquePérezHerrero  Creating a matrix and taking `diag` should be not efficient

Comment: Yes you lose the advantages of using  a `data.table`

Comment: @EnriquePérezHerrero  Yes, that is one problem, second is that creating matrix with huge datasets can take more memory along with `diag` should be slow

Comment: @EnriquePérezHerrero  If you are using `data.frame`, this can be made more efficient with row/column indexing i.e. `setDF(DT);
DT$W <- DT[cbind(1:nrow(DT), match(names(DT)[-3], DT$Z))]`